# Which of the following expressions is logarithmic?

Tags: data-structures, expression, big-o

Which of the following expressions is logarithmic out of O(logn) and O(nlogn) 
and how? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Well, O(log(n)) is logarithmic complexity while O(n*log(n)) is not, it is sometimes called linearithmic, loglinear or quasilinear.

Just look at the graphs of the two functions to see the difference.